# Show list of annotation in offline map in mapbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapbox, offline

I'm trying to show list of annotation /marker in offline mapbox. 
I'm trying to combine the source code given in the example to my needs.
So, I have a mbtiles source, I load it to mapView. and then I have a data contains list of coordinate. I want to show a marker based on the coordinates given in my Data.
But unfortunately I cant figure out why the markers are not seen in the map.
 Here is the code that I've ever done so far.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Data.h"
#import "Mapbox.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@end



@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"FieldIQ" ofType:@"mbtiles"];

    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];

    mapView.zoom = 3;

    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES; // these tiles aren't designed specifically for retina, so make them legible

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    self.arrayAnnotation = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    for(int i=0;i<appDelegate.datas.count;i++)
    {
        Data *data = (Data *)[appDelegate.datas objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"count %d : area %@ and name %@",i, data.addressGeographicalX, data.addressGeographicalY);

        NSString *trimlat = [data.addressGeographicalX stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSString *trimlon = [data.addressGeographicalY stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        //Convert to double
        double latdouble = [trimlat doubleValue];
        double londouble = [trimlon doubleValue];
        //Create coordinate
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {(latdouble),(londouble)};
        [mapView addAnnotation:[RMAnnotation annotationWithMapView:mapView coordinate:
                                mapView.centerCoordinate andTitle:nil]];

    }
    [mapView addAnnotation:[RMAnnotation annotationWithMapView:mapView coordinate:
                            mapView.centerCoordinate andTitle:nil]];
    mapView.clusteringEnabled = YES;




    //mapView.clusteringEnabled = YES;

}- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation)
        return nil;

    RMMapLayer *layer = nil;

    if (annotation.isClusterAnnotation)
    {
        layer = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle.png"]];

        layer.opacity = 0.75;

        // set the size of the circle
        layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);

        // change the size of the circle depending on the cluster's size
        if ([annotation.clusteredAnnotations count] > 2) {
            layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70);
        } else if ([annotation.clusteredAnnotations count] > 3) {
            layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        } else if ([annotation.clusteredAnnotations count] > 5) {
            layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120);
        }

        [(RMMarker *)layer setTextForegroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [(RMMarker *)layer changeLabelUsingText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",
                                                 (unsigned long)[annotation.clusteredAnnotations count]]];
    }
    else
    {
        layer = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithMapboxMarkerImage:@"rocket" tintColor:
                 [UIColor colorWithRed:0.224 green:0.671 blue:0.780 alpha:1.000]];
    }

    return layer;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you do a log statement and count the the number of annotations on the map to confirm they re not being added. i.e. the alpha is 0

Comment: ok. wait a minute.

Comment: @DogCoffee: Thanks for your suggestion that I got hint to trace it..

Answer (score 0):

This case is closed.
Sorry that I'm a newbie in Android.
Actually the markers are drawn. But I didnt delegate my mapView to itself so that the map layer doesnt show my markers. 
I solved it by Adding  in the header file and then call
mapView.delegate = self.

Comment: Adding <RMMapViewDelegate>